# Query a date column in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I need to query an existing database table that has a column of sql type `datetime`

EF Core maps DateTime properties to `[datetime2](7)` . That did not matter in EF Core 3.1.

Queries like `db.Blogs.Where( b => b.StartDate > new DateTime(2020,1,1))` were still translated to something like  `WHERE StartDate > '2020-01-01T00:00:00.00'`

I updated to EF to Core 6.0 and such a query now leads to something like `WHERE [StartDate] > '2020-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'` which works for a column of type `[datetime2](7)` but not of type `datetime`

Since the table is used by EF (Non core) and EF Core the column should stay `datetime` but I need to be able to filter it. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Putting single quotes around the DateTime will make it a string.  If database is a datetime2 than you need to take the string date an make it a datetime something like DateTime.Parse("2020-01-01T00:00:00.0000000")

Comment: The query is gernerated  by EF

Comment: @jdweng If I understood correctly, it is the other way around, the database is `datetime`, and core 6.0 creates query resulting `""2020-01-01T00:00:00.0000000""`, which do not work with `datetime` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need time info in query you can just drop it. You can use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method for .net version and [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.core.objects.entityfunctions.truncatetime?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)  method for core version. Just  truncate time info from column with time info.

```
db.Blogs.Where( b => b.StartDate > DbFunctions.TruncateTime(yourdateTime))
```

Should work.

Since the question is about EF Core it should be

```
db.Blogs.Where( b => b.StartDate.Date  > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(yourdateTime))
```

Comment: DbFunctions.TruncateTime is EF for  .NET not  EF  Core

Comment: But the equivalent  in core actually worked b.StartDate.Date > yourdateTime

Comment: I edited the answer. I hope thats ok for you

Comment: @MathiasF sorry I missed the core part.